# How to perform IF ELSE THEN T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to perform IF ELSE THEN in SQL Server ?

For example I want to perform `IF` my result of query is `NOT NULL` (My row is exist). It will continue to `THEN` statement

[image]

`ELSE` if my result of query is `NULL` (My row is doesn't exist), it will continue to another `THEN` statement

[image]

For T-SQL Example, this is just dummy SQL script

```
IF (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A) IS NOTNULL THEN
(INSERT INTO TABLE_B)
ELSE
(DIDN'T PERFORM ANY QUERY)
```

Thank you

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. And please only tag the relevant version of SQL Server, not multiple.

Comment: I assume you've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) so what about them is unclear? It seems the only change you need to make to your pseudo-code is use `exists` instead of `notnull`.

Comment: @DaleK I'm sorry, yeah it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the table returns any rows and then perform SELECT INTO operation

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A)
BEGIN 
    SELECT * INTO TABLE_B FROM TABLE_A
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use your `SELECT` statement in the `WHERE` clause of your `INSERT`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B(...)
    SELECT ...
        FROM ...
        WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A);
```

and then test wether anything was inserted with `IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to insert specific rows from A into B, then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B ( . . . )   -- list the columns here
    SELECT . . .
    FROM TABLE_A;
```

If there are no rows, then nothing gets inserted.  It is that simple.

Actually, it is simpler than that.  Using `IF` introduces race conditions in your code.  The `TABLE_A` could change between the execution of the `IF` and the `INSERT`, so the code is not thread-safe.  This code does not have that problem.